# How to effectively buffer and flush stream in Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, xml, excel, performance

I use OpenXML SDK 2.0 to generate Excel file with large amount of data, appox. 1000000 rows, and I need to optimize memory usage because my machine slows down very quickly.

I want to solve this issue by flushing part of generated DOM tree into file during runtime. I  make my own buffering for data. E.g I have 100000 records to write and I want flush stream into file when I add 1000 rows into Excel worksheet. I make this by using method worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save().
Documantation says that this method Save(): "saves the data in the DOM tree back to the part. It could be called multiple times as well. Each time it is called, the stream will be flushed."

```
         foreach (Record m in dataList)
         {
            Row contentRow = CreateContentRow(index, m);         // my own method to create row content

            //Append new row to sheet data.
            sheetData.AppendChild(contentRow);

            if (index % BufferSize == 0)
            {
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            }

            index++;

        }
```

This method works because memory usage chart has saw shape but unfortunetly the memory uasge grows in time.

Do anyone have any idea how solve this issue?

Comment: @karolryz, just for the clarity, why did you mark the @Joe Erickson's answer as accepted whereas `SpreadsheetGear for .NET` is not about `Open XML SDK`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can create an xlsx workbook with 1,000,000 rows by 40 columns of random numbers (that's 40 million cells) in 74 seconds (that includes creating the workbook in memory from random numbers and saving to disk on an overclocked Intel QX 6850 and Windows Vista 32).

What kind of performance are you seeing with the Open XML SDK?

You can download a free trial of SpreadsheetGear [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) and try it yourself.

I will past the code to generate the 40 million cell workbook below.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SpreadsheetGear;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Run once with 100 rows and then run forever with 1,000,000 rows.
                for (int rows = 100; rows <= 1000000; rows = 1000000)
                {
                    Console.Write("rows={0}, ", rows);
                    var startMemory = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
                    var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    var workbook = BuildWorkbook(rows);
                    var usedMemory = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - startMemory;
                    Console.WriteLine("usedMemory={0}, time={1} seconds, workbook.Name={2}", usedMemory, timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, workbook.Name);
                    workbook = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("got exception={0}", e.Message);
            }
        }

        static IWorkbook BuildWorkbook(int rows)
        {
            var workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            var values = (SpreadsheetGear.Advanced.Cells.IValues)worksheet;
            Random rand = new Random();
            int cols = 40;
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row <= rows; row++)
                {
                    values.SetNumber(row, col, rand.NextDouble());
                }
            }
            workbook.SaveAs(string.Format(@"c:\tmp\Rows{0}.xlsx", rows), FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
            return workbook;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check if SpreadsheetGear help me to solve my issue.
I desribe my Open XML SDK performaance problem on this post:http://blog.goyello.com/2009/08/25/read-before-using-it-open-xml-sdk-performance-analysis/

Comment: A perfectly worded question that pops up as first result in Google. Viewed 1200 times. And the only answer is a pitiful plug for a third party retail library???

Comment: Especially since it is a very pricey third party library.  At $1000, spreadsheetgear is way too expensive.

Comment: @mdisibio The "pitiful plug" also seems to have a working code example and a free trial. The best answer to software problems isn't always "free" or "roll your own."

Comment: @john Wow. Reading my comment, it certainly comes across as rude. My apologies. It was not directed to you. It was to say "Hey, this is a popular question for devs using the OpenXml library, doesn't anyone on SO have an answer outside of the suggestion to buy a third party app?"

Comment: @john Just to be clear, this issue has nothing to do with your product. The OpenXml api, as it is delivered to developers, does not offer much flexibility in memory management. However, with all due respect, including a third party licenced library in enterprise applications, and I am sure yours is well written, is sometimes viable but other times comes with its own set of problems, especially in the area of long-term maintenance, and is not always the best answer to a software problem either.

Comment: @mdisibio No need to apologize to me; it's not my library. I haven't even used the library(ies) in question. So, the code example might not work, I suppose. On the whole, I think the SO community unfairly discounts solutions that involve commercial libraries posted by their owners. Yes, he does stand to gain financially if the library is used, but if it solves the problem (possibly in a pinch) then everyone wins. Anyway, have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is opposite approach to the "buffer and flush" for the task of writing large Excel files. The approach is based on using the OpenXmlWriter class and uses sequential writing instead of buffering and flushing. A one typical solution also uses replacement part and OpenXmlReader to get unchanged content from a template. Look at ["Writing Large Excel Files with the Open XML SDK"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brian_jones/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk) (with a few code examples) and ["Write large OpenXML docs"](http://www.cdwaddell.com/blog/?p=34) (with complete code example).

Comment: I was going to point that out, but I see you already did. This ought to be the accepted answer, because it's the correct solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @Mahen, I fixed the first link (Microsoft do not respect Web and developers: the company do not maintain redirections). The second link is under fixing.